# Is there an easy way to clone an object and unset some properties at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel

In PHP / Laravel, I am looking for an easier way to do the following in one line:

```
$newItem = clone $item;
unset($newItem->property1);
unset($newItem->property2);
```

I know I can create a helper method for it, but maybe there is one in Laravel already and i wasn't aware of.

Comment: WHY? How likely is it that something that specific will be in builtin code. Unless you write it

Comment: Why do you require this? Laravel does have `pop` and other useful methods on collections but cloning an object and unsetting properties? like what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$newItem = clone $item;
unset($newItem->property1, $newItem->property2);
```

you can also define a `__clone` method in your object

```php
public function __clone(): void
{
    unset($this->property1, $this->property2);
}
```

and if your `$item` is a model you can do:

```php
$newItem = $item->replicate(['property1', 'property2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There sure is a one liner and is mostly only useful for scenarios where you want to unset multiple properties.

Convert the object to an array via typecasting, filter the keys that are required and cast them back to an object.

```
<?php

$newItem = (object)(array_filter((array)$item, fn($k) => !in_array($k, ['property1', 'property2']), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY ));

var_dump($newItem);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/UqZJN)